# Rails: Facebook Omniauth + Devise. How to get movie likes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise

I'm using the [Facebook Oauth gem](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook) with devise. Here is my setup:

```
config.omniauth :facebook, Figaro.env.facebook_app_id, Figaro.env.facebook_app_secret, 
                  scope: 'email, user_friends, public_profile, user_birthday, user_actions.video',
                  info_fields: 'email,first_name,last_name,gender, birthday, location',
                  :image_size => 'normal'
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get the movies a person likes (e.g. on your profile page, scroll down, you have a 'movies' section that you can like/rate etc). I added user_actions.video to my scope but nothing coming back in response.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.5#reference-user_likes) out.

simply you need to add `user_likes` scope to the list of scopes, you mentioned above.

#### Update

Please use a gem called `"koala"` to extract info from facebook.

see this [link](http://www.launchschool.com/blog/facebook-graph-api-using-omniauth-facebook-and-koala) for detailed info on how to integrate `koala with omniauth`.

Also this this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/movies/) which shows the exact api url to get the movies that specific user likes.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what info_field I need to get for movies? I tried adding movies but no data is being returned..